# Modifying elements in a STL List - C++

Tags: c++, list, tree, iterator, constants

I am attempting to construct a binary search tree using a generalized list in C++.

```
class Element
{
private:
       list<Element*> _children;
       char* _name;
// and other data members/methods...
}
```

As you can see, I have a class "Element" and it has a list "_children" of Element pointers.

I am trying to access these children so that I may add children to them and so forth...

However, I cannot modify these values with my current method of using a "const_iterator" and my reason for doing that is that the "begin()" method of _children returns a const_iterator.

Someone help? Thank you :)

UPDATE: Thank you all so much... It turns out, I mistakenly had a method return a const reference of the _children data member.

```
const list<Element*>& getChildren();// return [_children]
```

I just deleted const and it works perfect now. Thank you! :D

Comment: Look at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin). `begin()` only returns a `const_iterator` if you give it a const object. This makes perfect sense. Getting back an iterator that can change a constant value from such normal usage would be poor design.

Comment: My guess is you're calling `_children.begin()` within a `const` member function. And are you sure you need a `list<Element*>` and not just a `list<Element>`, or even `vector<Element>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The begin function will return a `const_iterator` if the list is const. So for the `_children` list you should be able to just get the standard iterator to let you perform non-const operations on it:

```
list<Element*>::iterator it = _children.begin();
```

This however won't work if your passing off a const reference to the list and then trying to get the non-const iterator from that. Something like this would not be allowed:

```
void doSomething( const list<Element*>& l )
{
    list<Element*>::iterator it = l.begin();
}
```

You would need to instead pass a non-const reference to the list.

The other case where this would be not allowed is in a const function, i.e.

```
void doSomething() const
{
    list<Element*>::iterator it = _children.begin();
}
```

But would need to see more of your code to confirm if you're doing this or not.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use _children as an array, how about trying std::vector class instead of std::list?

Here's usage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
    std::vector<int> list;
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.capacity();++i){
        std::cout << list[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah the OP should probably use a `vector` instead of a `list`, but this in no way answers the question he's asking.